# Reactive Extension .Net - High Availability

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, high-availability

We have used Reactive Extension to trigger certain actions at specific time.

Ex: Two minutes after a specific user action do something.

Syntax :

```
var observable = Observable.Timer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, someTime)).Take(1);
var subscribe = observable.Subscribe(i =>
                    {
                        DoSomething();
                        }
                    });
```

But now if the IIS / server is restarted, this trigger is lost. This is required to be persisted as we have high available deployment with multiple App Servers hosting the code.

Help us in coming with an approach to solve this.

Comment: What all have you tried?

Comment: We thought of using Quartz.Net cluster as an alternative but it would mean changing the existing code.

Comment: Persistence of program state is too complex an issue to generalize. Are all of your callbacks non-capturing?

Comment: Also note that while Rx is not the answer here (use Hangfire, or a messaging technology), you dont need a `Take(1)` on an `Observable.Timer()` call. It will only produce a single value of `0` after the specified period.

Comment: Have you considered creating a windows service (TopShelf can help with tis) to host the rx portion in?  This will alleviate losing triggers due to IIS restarts.  The windows service can notify the web site via  webhook.  This is not THE answer, just another option to consider.  Using a message bus instead of a webhook to connect windows service/web app would even be better.

Answer (score 4):

> But now if the IIS / server is restarted, this trigger is lost. This
>   is required to be persisted as we have high available deployment with
>   multiple App Servers hosting the code.

Probably Reactive Extensions aren't the answer here.

It seems like you should use message queues or a *service bus*.

Check these technologies if you want to dig more about this approach:

- [MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx).
- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)
- [Azure Service Bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/)

Also, take a look at [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/), a service bus that can use some of above mentioned messaging technologies.